# Image impressions vrs Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, impressions

can any help?
Currently I have page with an image loading. Every time the image loads I write to a database:

Count = Count +1
I have tested my code by refreshing my page and the image count works correctly (going up by one each time).

Currently the count for this month is over 60,000, however in Google Analytics on that page it shows the pageview as 1800 and the unique pageview even less.

Has anyone any idea why the numbers are so far apart from my count and Google pageview.
How does Google calculate it's pageviews? Are spiders the issue?

Thanks

Comment: is the visits number any close to those 60,000?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics records data using an image request sent via Javascript -- meaning most bots/spiders won't show up.

I'd suggest taking at look at your server logs. Each image request you're tracking should have a corresponding page request. Maybe your image is being hotlinked?